# C# BackgroundWorker skips DoWork and goes straight to RunWorkerCompleted

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

I'm new with C# so go easy on me!

So far - I have a console app that listens for client connections and replies to the client accordingly.

I also have a WPF form with a button and a text box.  The button launches some code to connect to the server as a BackgroundWorker, which then waits for a response before appending it to the end of the text box.

This works great, once.  Sometimes twice.  But then it kept crashing - turns out that the DoWork block wasn't being called at all and it was going straight to RunWorkerCompleted.  Of course, the .result is blank so trying to convert it to a string fails.

Is this a rookie mistake?  I have tried searching the internet for various ways of saying the above but haven't come across anything useful...

This is the code so far: http://pastebin.com/ZQvCFqxN - there are so many debug outputs from me trying to figure out exactly what went wrong.

This is the result of the debug outputs: http://pastebin.com/V412mppX

Any help much appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT: The relevant code *post-fix* (thanks to Patrick Quirk below) is:

```
public void dorequest(string query)
{
    request = new BackgroundWorker();
    request.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    request.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    request.ProgressChanged += request_ProgressChanged;
    request.DoWork += request_DoWork;
    request.RunWorkerCompleted += request_RunWorkerCompleted; 
    request.RunWorkerAsync(query);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're attaching your `DoWork` handler after calling `RunWorkerAsync`.  Flip those around and that should fix it.

*Also, in the future please paste code in your question rather than using an external site.  And when possible give the smallest amount of code that demonstrates the problem.  Makes it easier on us and people who might have the same issue.*

Comment: post your addendum as a comment instead perhaps?

Comment: I've pasted it in to the original request - that should hopefully be enough to help others with similar issues